# How to use For loop or While loop parsing JSONObjects

Tags: java, android, json, loops

Currently I am using an Iterator loop to parse my JSON objects. Works well for a small to medium dataset. But when my dataset increases, so does the performance time. For example:

```js
 //groupedData is my JSONObject dataset
Iterator<String> iter = groupedData.keys();
            int i = 0;
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                String key = iter.next();
                try {
                    Object value = groupedData.get(key);
                  //add the value to an entry
                    values_1.add(new Entry(Float.valueOf(String.valueOf(value)), i));
                  //add key to an arraylist
                    labels_1.add(key);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // Something went wrong!
                }
                i++;
            }
```

I used these Iterator loops for like 4 more different datasets. It ends up taking forever to loop through everything.

After digging, I got this lead [which showed results show that the Iterator mechanism is the slowest method to loop through a list. There's not much performance difference between the For and the While loop.](https://www.mkyong.com/java/while-loop-for-loop-and-iterator-performance-test-java/)

So is there a better way to loop through JSON Objects using the For or WHile loops?

My JSONObject data is like:

```js
{
  "Admin": 19900,
  "James": 2000,
  "Steve": 1501,
  "Linda": 3840,
  "Grace": 2170,
  "Jeff": 1200,
  "Carolle": 350
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using `GSON`? I suggest you give it a try.

Comment: I haven't tried yet, mind sharing an example?

Comment: Do not make your own JSON parsers, there are libraries out there to do this like GSON or JACKSON.

Comment: @GherbiHicham how i'm i making my own Json parser? This is an iterator loop to get each json object key and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#serializing-and-deserializing-generic-types) to parse the `JSON`.

Try this,

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String,String> map = new Gson().fromJson(groupedData.toString(), type);
```